# Query for students reg in courses year wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this type of data, how it is possible for me using SQL Server? I'm using SQL Server Pivot table

Here is my query, in which I'm using Pivot, but this will not applicable as per my requirement.

Is Pivot table not the solution?

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME((SessionName)) +', 0) AS ' + (SessionName) + '' 
                        FROM SIS_tbl_AdmissionSession
                        GROUP BY SessionName 
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(SessionName)
                      FROM SIS_tbl_AdmissionSession 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 
SET @query = '
      SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT a.AdmissionID, a.CourseID,c.sessionname, b.ProgramName, a.StudentName, a.AdmSessionID
      FROM SIS_tbl_AdmissionForm a
      INNER JOIN SIS_tbl_Programs b
      ON a.CourseID = b.ProgramId
      INNER JOIN SIS_tbl_AdmissionSession c
      ON a.admsessionid = c.admsessionid
      ) StudentResults
      PIVOT (
      SUM(AdmissionID)
      FOR StudentName
      IN ( '+ @cols +' )) AS PivotTable '

execute(@query)
```

```
SessionYr(dynamic)   Program Name (dynamic)
---------           --------------------------------
2020-2021           OPHTHALMIC O.T.TECHNICIAN COURSE
2020-2021           OPHTHALMIC O.T.TECHNICIAN COURSE
2020-2021           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2020-2021           REFRACTIONIST COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2019-2020           OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE
2020-2021           REFRACTIONIST COURSE
2020-2021           REFRACTIONIST COURSE
```

I want this

```
Course Name                          2020-2021    2019-2020    ToTal
-----------------------------        ----------   ---------    -----
OPHTHALMIC TECHNICIANS COURSE           2            1          3 
REFRACTIONIST COURSE                    0            2          2
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I use SQL Pivot

Comment: Kindly check the above SQL query

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of session years, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select program_name,
    sum(case when sessionyr = '2020-2021' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_20_21,
    sum(case when sessionyr = '2019-2020' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_19_20,
    count(*) as total
from mytable
group by program_name
```

If you want something that dynamically creates columns according to the distinct years, then you need *dynamic SQL*, which is a more complicated syntax.

Comment: No I have dynamic sessions, and programs each coming from different table